# Tooltip Options not working for Highcharts Treemap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, treemap

I want to add some tooltip formatting to a Highcharts treemap. For example the `valueSuffix` or `valueDecimals`.
I have no problems using those attributes with different chart types but somehow they don't work for treemaps.

Here is the example code and [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyzfw5Ly/) where I tried to use them.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: '#00FF00',
            valueSuffix: 'E',
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
        series: [{
            type: "treemap",
            layoutAlgorithm: 'stripes',
            alternateStartingDirection: true,
            levels: [{
            }]
        }]
    });
```

as you can see, the background-color attribute works.

I know that I could use the formatter with a function, but I prefer using the properties provided by Highcharts.

According to the documentation, you can also use series.tooltip or plotOptions.treemap.tooltip properties for styling but they did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the reporting. Looks like a bug, which I added to our tracker here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5352

Comment: it is now resolved in the latest highcharts version, so if you had the same problem you can update now (version: Highcharts 4.2.6 (2016-08-02))

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to push what appears to be a missing value in `pointArrayMap` manually.

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyzfw5Ly/1/)):

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype.pointArrayMap.push('node.val');
```